# how to reference a vector as an argument

Tags: c++, function, vector

could someone please help me with my adder function? I think it is almost correct however, I need help knowing the proper way to pass myVector and I'm not sure how to do so. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> Adder(std::vector<std::string> myVector);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inventory;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator myIter;

    inventory.push_back("sword");
    inventory.push_back("bow");
    inventory.push_back("shield");
    inventory.push_back("armor");

    for (myIter = inventory.begin(); myIter != inventory.end(); myIter++)
    {
        std::cout << *myIter << "\n";
    }

    Adder(inventory);

    for (myIter = inventory.begin(); myIter != inventory.end(); myIter++)
    {
        std::cout << *myIter << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}


std::vector<std::string> Adder(std::vector<std::string> myVector)
{
    std::string prompt;

    std::cout << "Enter a new item to add to your inventory: ";
    std::cin >> prompt;

    myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), prompt);

    return myVector;
}
```

Comment: Also, why do people vote this question down? Is this considered a bad question for this forum?

Comment: _'Is this considered a bad question for this forum?'_ Yes, since there isn't really question. Please be specific with your actual problems (compiler errors/runtime exceptions/unexpected behavior), instead of us letting find out. Also please refer here 1st, [what and how you can ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The reason it got downvoted is probably because it is not a well formed question. You've done well by showing your code, but you haven't explained the problem precisely. You should specify each of the following: 1. For a given sample input, the expected output. 2. For the same sample input, the observed output. 3. A full and exact copy-paste of any error messages you're getting (if applicable). Furthermore, if possible narrow your code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and cut out all irrelevant text (e.g. that you've been reading about vectors in a book).

Comment: Okay, I'll remember that for next time. Thank you @JBentley

Comment: @BobRoss there isn't actually a question in the post, nor is there any indication of why the code doesn't meet your expectations. Consider editing the question to include these things, even though it's already been solved. Questions that get upvotes are ones that may be useful to other people searching the site for their problem in future. For example a more descriptive title would be "Changes to vector in function not appearing in main()"

Comment: It's good that you posted a complete program though.

Comment: @BobRoss You can edit this question and add that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::string> Adder(std::vector<std::string> myVector);
```

Your `Adder` function takes the `vector` by value. This means a copy of the `vector` is passed to this function, and any modifications you make are obviously not seen by the copy within `main()`.

You should change the function to:

```
void Adder(std::vector<std::string>& myVector);
```

Now the argument is being taken by reference, any modifications you make to it are being made to the original object.

---

Another option is to leave the function as it is, and replace the `vector` in `main()` with the value returned by the function.

```
std::vector<std::string> inventory;
// ... stuff

inventory = Adder(inventory); // the original is replaced with the return value

// rest of your code
```

In your case I'd prefer the first approach.

Comment: good, I also prefer first, maybe with pointers +1

Comment: @Andres You mean the parameter type should be `vector<string>*` instead of `vector<string>&`? Why?

Comment: no, I just mean that we can also use `vector<string>*` and `->` when is necessary, just another way to get it

Comment: @Andres You could do it that way, but in most cases it is an inferior way to do it. Pretty much the only time you should consider making a parameter a pointer type instead of a reference type is if your function should be able to handle `nullptr` as an argument, or you need to interop with C code.

Answer (score 0):

use `Adder(std::vector<std::string> &myVector)` when you declare the method so it will use a reference of the vector instead a copy as you was doing.

when you don't use & only the copy gets the new value. you can also use pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
void Adder(std::vector<std::string> &myVector);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inventory;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator myIter;
    inventory.push_back("sword");
    inventory.push_back("bow");
    inventory.push_back("shield");
    inventory.push_back("armor");
    for (myIter = inventory.begin(); myIter != inventory.end(); myIter++)
        std::cout<<*myIter<<"\n";

    Adder(inventory);

    for (myIter = inventory.begin(); myIter != inventory.end(); myIter++)
        std::cout<<*myIter<<"\n";

    return 0;
}

void Adder(std::vector<std::string> &myVector)
{
    std::string prompt;
    std::cout<<"Enter a new item to add to your inventory: ";
    std::cin>>prompt;

    myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), prompt);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you! Man such a simple little thing. I would never thought of referencing it. I've touched on pointers and referencing a little but not much.

Comment: @BobRoss the answer was simple but you have to learn this well, also read about pointers, it could be a bit more complex but they are really useful and funny

Comment: @Andres it makes no sense to take the vector by reference and also return it

Comment: @MattMcNabb you are right, I just add '&' to give him the correct answer.

Comment: By the way, should I delete this answer? there is already a good answer with a better explanation

Comment: up to you. I'd edit it to fix the problem with returning and also taking by reference , there's no harm in leaving it up after that